# Why does std::copy_n take a template parameter instead of std::size_t?

Tags: c++, c++11

So simple question.

```
template<class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n(InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result);
```

Why does `std::copy_n` take a type for the number of elements it's going to copy instead of simply `std::size_t`? I just can't think of a reason.

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy_n(InputIt first, std::size_t count, OutputIt result);
```

Comment: Let's say if the developer suddenly call that function with parameter count is a `signed int` and it have negative value, if `count` is `std::size_t`, it will do integral promotion, then we will receive an undefined behavior.

Comment: One obvious case is when the size required could be larger than the maximum value of `size_t`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speculating about original rationales is mostly futile in such a case, but with this design [`copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) can be invoked with a negative count of e.g. `int` or `ptrdiff_t` type, in which case it simply does nothing, and that must surely have been clear to the standardization committee's members, who are pretty competent folks.

---

One additional advantage is that with special iterators, such as input and output iterators, the size might be larger than any possible pointer difference, and hence possibly larger than `size_t` can represent. E.g. this is so for files larger than 4GB in 32-bit Windows. The definition of `copy_n` is expressed in terms of apparent pointer/iterator arithmetic, “For each non-negative integer `i < n`, performs `*(result + i) = *(first + i)`”, which would seem to relegate this advantage to very special cases indeed, but the notation accommodates pure input and output iterators as explained in

C++11 §25.1/12:

> **”** In the description of the algorithms operators `+` and `-` are used for some of the iterator categories for which
>   they do not have to be defined. In these cases the semantics of `a+n` is the same as that of
>
> ```
> X tmp = a;
> advance(tmp, n);
> return tmp;
> ```
>
> and that of `b-a` is the same as of `return distance(a, b)`;

---

The genericity of the design has no inherent advantage, rather it's a disadvantage in itself in that it's more verbose and generates less easily understood diagnostics for incorrect usage code. Its advantages include the two ones listed above. Evidently the committee felt that these advantages, and perhaps others (?), outweighed the inherent disadvantages of having `Size` as a template parameter.

Comment: They could've specified that unless called with an unsigned integer type then the behaviour would be undefined. Because the whole idea of std::copy_n is to copy n-amount of elements. Can't be negative, can't be non-integral, because we are dealing with a number of elements.

Comment: @DeiDei: there are plausible (though not IMHO convincing) arguments for using signed types for container sizes: while I disagree with much he says on that and other topics, Lakos outlines them ad nauseum in his Large Scale C++ book if you're interested, but the best is supporting naive/intuitive use of `abs(c1.size() - c2.size())`.  Further, things like untyped macros might be used to provide a size, and will default to `int` unless too large.  Having *undefined behaviour* if such types are casually passed to `copy_n` is a totally unnecessary and *very* dangerous idea.

Comment: @DeiDei: I'm curious why having `n` be a generically typed template parameter might be a problem?  I imagine that there are very few times when the types for `copy_n()` are explicitly specified instead of being inferred. What's the downside to the current specification of `copy_n()`? There's a clear upside to avoiding implicit signed-to-unsigned conversions.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess it is because of **genericity**.
Containers `size_type` in C++ are usually `size_t`. But if you use a custom container, or use custom allocators, that might not be the case hence the template parameter.

For a [custom container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container), `size_type` does not have to be a typedef  to `size_t` (it has to be `an unsigned integer large enough to represent all positive values of difference_type`).

For STL containers, `size_type` is a typedef to `allocator::size_type` which is `size_t` for the [default allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator). But the type can be different if you specify a custom allocator.

Comment: It could be `iterator_traits<OutputIt>::difference_type`. And specify that `distance(result, return_value) == count`. But then it would have vague meaning for input-only and output-only iterators.

Comment: @ConstantinBaranov: In C++11 `copy_n` is specified as "For each non-negative integer i < n, performs *(result + i) = *(first + i)". That's not compatible with input-only or output-only iterators. But then, `copy` is also specified that way, and can be used with such iterators. Hm. Worthy of investigation.

Comment: Oh, that's defined in C++11 §25.1/12. Learned something today too, then. Not yet dead, hallelujah! Oh, dang, I'm atheist. Well, anyway.